# Accessing warden login information in Sinatra test response

Tags: ruby, sinatra, warden

Practically everything I am looking for is said in the title - I need to access warden user variable in test to check whether authentication worked. Another way is also possible for me, just trying to test authentication nicely :)

```
should "authenticate" do
    post "/login", {:login => "test_login", :password => "password"}, {"HTTP_HOST" => "test.host"}
    assert last_response.redirect?
    assert_equal last_response.env["warden"].user.login, "test_login"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get at the internal request environment in a rack-test-style full-stack test. If you want to verify that you've been logged in as a specific user you'll need to look at something like the redirect URL (if it redirects to a user-identifiable URL) or follow the redirect (easy with `rack-test`'s `follow_redirect!` helper) and then look for evidence of the User ID in the HTML.

I would have thought that you don't really need to test Warden itself, but you will want to make sure you're providing the correct information to it, and aren't mangling it in the middleware stack.

You might find something like [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) handy for doing genuine form-filling and submission.

Finally, Warden has its own test helpers (which definitely work with `rack-test`) so you can set up a request to be logged in without having to actually run through the logging in request/redirect cycle in each test - https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/testing has more details.